# Download and install JavaFX for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

I'm an experienced (Java, Eclipse & Maven) developer, and have used a couple of frameworks thus far. Every time I'm trying to start with something new, it seems like there are about a zillion configuration possible for downloading and installing it.

I've looked [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.2/gettingstarted/eclipse-plugin/index.html#downloadinfo) for instructions, and all the near pages, but they seem out dated, the Eclipse plugin path is invalid, and when I install the latest version I've found no the site (2.0.2), it says that I have a newer version installed.

Also, the Maven setup in most posts I've read seems obscure.

**I'm using:**

- Windows 7
- Eclipse x64 Indigo
- JDK x64 1.6.0.24
- Maven 3.0.3

And I don't recall installing the JavaFX.

What an I missing? Where can I read about the setup in order to start working with this framework?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JavaFX gets installed if you install the latest JDK 7 from Oracle (co-bundled).

You can find the Eclipse plugin here:

http://efxclipse.org/

If your're interested in Maven builds: I've recently released an initial version of Drombler FX, a modular RCP for JavaFX based on OSGi and Maven (POM-first):

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/12/drombler-fx-building-modular-javafx.html

http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted

Comment: Note that e(fx)clipse requires at least Java7u7

Comment: And also note that Oracle's Java SE 6 reaches EOL at the end of the month: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: I'm now starting to integrate the Media player into a Swing application and I can't help but notice there are three threads being created and destroyed rapidly... Isn't this some sort of an abuse? Why not to queue the darn Runnables?

Comment: @TacB0sS If you find issues, you can file them here: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com If you want to dig into the implementation of JavaFX yourself consider to subscribe to the mailing list: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev

Answer (score 1):

I did tried **efxclipse** but it was not enough for me. I have also tried to give the path of javafx jar file to **efxclipse**

> Window->Prefrences->javafx->"The path to javafx jar which is
>   **jfxrt.jar**"

. **But nothing worked** for me I don't know what was going wrong.

Then I just add the **jfxrt.jar** file to my Library and everything worked fine :-

```
 1. Right click your JRE System Library
 2. Build Path
 3. Configure Build Path
 4. Add External Jars
 5. "The path to jfxrt.jar"
```

You can download **jfxrt.jar** file from [this](https://github.com/qweasdzxcpoi/JavaFX/raw/master/jfxrt.jar) link.

Or

If you have already downloaded the latest oracle JAVA JDK you will find in this path

> Extracted_oracle_jdk_folder/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar

That's it everything should work fine.

Comment: Nobody should ever do such a nonsens as downloading a separate jfxrt.jar which may not even be compatible with your current java version. The Oracle JDK contains the right jar and you don't have to add that explicitly to the build path.

Answer (score 0):

Try e(fx)clipse at http://efxclipse.org/. I'm a netbeans developer, but heard a lot of good stuff about that plugin from my eclipse using friends.